# Complejidad temporal y espacial de un algoritmo

Tags: java

una pregunta alguien podria ayudarme a saber cual es la complejidad temporal y espacial de este algoritmo :D... Es sobre encontrar un numero repetido en un arreglo

```
***public static int numRepetido(int numeros[]) {
    int num = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<numeros.length/2; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<numeros.length; j++) {
            if(numeros[i] == numeros[j]) {
                num = numeros[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}***
```

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]. Te invito a leer [ask] y a realizar el [tour]. ¿Qué has investigado al respecto? Una investigación previa te habría dado una respuesta a este ejercicio, sin embargo has preferido escribir directamente tu duda aquí sin investigar previamente. Evita hacerlo, ya que este tipo de preguntas terminan cerradas. Saludos

Answer (score 2):

Primero hay que saber que es una complejidad temporal y que es una complejidad espacial:

**La complejidad temporal** de un algoritmo se refiere a cuánto tiempo toma el algoritmo para completarse su ejecución en función del tamaño de la entrada. Por lo general, se mide en términos del número de operaciones que realiza el algoritmo, ya que esto afecta directamente su velocidad de ejecución.

**La complejidad espacial** de un algoritmo se refiere a cuánto espacio en memoria utiliza el algoritmo para completarse su ejecución. Esto incluye no solo el espacio que ocupan los datos de entrada, sino también el espacio utilizado por el algoritmo para almacenar resultados intermedios o cualquier otra información que necesite durante su ejecución.

Dicho esto analicemos ese algoritmo.

```
public static int numRepetido(int numeros[]) {
    int num = -1;
    for(int i=0; i<numeros.length/2; i++) {
        for(int j=i+1; j<numeros.length; j++) {
            if(numeros[i] == numeros[j]) {
                num = numeros[j];
            }
        }
    }
    return num;
}
java
```

**Explicacion:**

Lo que esta buscando este algoritmo es encontrar un número repetido en un arreglo de enteros.

Para realizar esto recorre el arreglo desde el índice 0 hasta la mitad del tamaño del Arreglo.

Dentro del bucle existe otro bucle que recorre el arreglo desde el índice i+1 hasta el final del arreglo. Dentro de este segundo bucle, el algoritmo comprueba si el numero de la posición i es igual al número de la posicion j.

Luego establece la condicion. Por lo tanto Si lo es, guarda este numero en la variable "num" y finaliza la ejecucion del algoritmo.

**Respuesta:**

Por lo tanto dada todas las explicaciones anteriores:

***La complejidad temporal de este algoritmo es O(n^2)***, ya que tiene dos bucles anidados y su tiempo de ejecución depende netamente del tamaño del arreglo.

***La complejidad espacial es O(1)*** ya que no utiliza ninguna estructura de datos adicional para almacer los numeros y solo requiere una variable para almacenar el resultado.

Espero esta explicacion te sirva de ayuda para entenderlo de mejor forma.

Comment: Evita responder preguntas que no muestran una clara investigación por parte del OP. [es.so] no está pensado como una gran Wikipedia, su propósito es resolver problemas específicos, en los que el OP está realmente involucrado, mostrando su esfuerzo mediante un [mcve] o con enlaces a la documentación que haya leído o investigado. Por otro lado, toma en cuenta que el uso de chatGPT está prohibido en el sitio, por no mencionar que si has hecho uso del mismo sin mencionarlo se considera plagio. Saludos

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu contribución, te sugerimos revisar: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5450/cheatgpt-chatgpt-nos-ha-alcanzado-en-soes